# How to pronounce "Question"?

Tags: pronunciation

/ˈkwestʃən/ or /ˈkwesʃən/ or both?
The dictionary says that it should be pronounced like "kwes+chun", but our teacher says "kwes-shun", and insists that both pronunciations are acceptable. He does the same for "suggestion". Is that really true?

Comment: Actually, a very similar question was asked earlier, but it didn't mention [ˈkwesʃən]: [How to pronounce 'question'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286932/how-to-pronounce-question)

Comment: If one has consumed a mild overdose of ethanol, your teacher's pronunciation may be appropriate.  Do not drive or operate machinery while speaking this way, however.

Comment: @sumelic That post didn't have a decent answer, so I've rectified that with a Wiki one. The wrong answer at the top needs downvoting.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a native english speaker with a slight east London accent. I pronounce it kwes-chun, as do most people I work with.

I have only heard question pronounced kwes-shun after the speaker has consumed vast amounts of alcohol and is slurring their words.  Additionally, posher accents are more clipped and it can sound like kwes-tee-un, same as kwes-chun but with less "ch".

Answer (score 2):

In all standard dialects of English, *question* is [pronounced](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/question?s=t) /ˈkwɛs tʃən/.

The closest case to pronouncing *question* with the sh-sound rather than the ch would be how some speakers drop the t-sound in *actual* so it's pronounced /ˈæk ʃu əl/. This is simply one unvoiced stop (t) assimilating to another (k).

Speakers of [AAVE](http://www.rehabmed.ualberta.ca/spa/phonology/features.htm) (African American Vernacular English) often drop final-t in words like *breakfast*, so if *quest* is pronounced *ques'*, then *que-shun* shouldn't be far behind.

Be that as it may, the standard pronunciation of *question* still obtains, regardless of what you're teacher says, and it isn't /ˈkwɛs ʃən/ or /ˈkwɛ ʃən/.

Comment: The LPD, the phoneticians gold standard of pronunciation dictionaries, gives both /ˈkweʃʧən/ and /'kwestjən/ as common alternative standard pronunciations of *question*.

Answer (score 0):

"Kwes-shun" is an elision. Elisions are not wrong, they're a normal acceptable part of speaking. It's basically an informal or colloquial contraction.

Dunno and kinda are elisions.
"Choc-late" and "as-prin" are also elisions (these are 3 syllable words that everyone says as two syllables).
Anywhere you drop a t or other hard sound out of the middle of a word, that is an elision (aye aye, cap'n).

It's a natural offshoot of the fact that your cerebellum doesn't want to coordinate awkward mouth movements, so you naturally smooth out words when speaking.

Your teacher was right; elisions are perfectly acceptable in spoken language as long as the result is not ambiguous.

Comment: Where is this particular pronunciation ("kwes-shun") normal? When I speak (even quickly), I hear a /t/.

Comment: It doesn't need to be normal to be acceptable. That said, I think "quesh'n" happens more often than most US speakers would credit, because it goes right under the radar.

Comment: Henry Higgins would have labelled some elisions 'wrong', Holly. 'Chocolate' is normally pronounced with the elision; pronouncing a full 'o' would be considered at best quirky. 'Aspirin' is pronounced as a two-syllable word almost universally in the UK; a schwa can be more apparent in the US. 'Elisions are perfectly acceptable in spoken language as long as the result is not ambiguous' is far too broad-brush.