# I pronounce question as kweshtin. Is my pronunciation wrong?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, dialects

I've lived in Houston,TX for about 10 years and after that I moved to the ME and I've made friends since then. Whenever they heard me say kweshtin they told me my pronunciation was weird. I told them that it's the American pronunciation, but when I googled it I found nothing to back me up. The results showed me that I should pronounce it as kweschin?

Comment: You probably want to wait for more answers before you check off one as 'accepted'. That tends to discourage more answers (and I think you would get more perspectives).

Comment: Do you really mean "kweshtin" and not "kweshchin"?

Comment: I've heard it pronounced a dozen different ways.  The last syllable does approximate "chin", but the "ch" is fairly percussive.  If you think about it, a question is a quest for an answer, so quest (with the T) is a reasonable start.   But English tends to blend the last bits of such a word into the start of a subsequent "-ion" suffix, producing a slight "ch" sound.

Comment: /'kwɛʃtən/ (which is what I take "kweshtin" to mean) is well within the range of possibilities in American English. Also common are /'kwɛʃtʃən/, /'kwɛstʃən/, /'kwɛʃtən/, and /'kwɛʃʃən/. Sibilants are hard to pronounce together and corners get cut.

Comment: Also see *[Is “question” pronounced with an “s” or with an “sh” sound?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286932/)* and *[How to pronounce “Question”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429562)*

Comment: I feel a bit more reassured knowing that there are other possible pronunciations for the word question.

Comment: I personally tend to pronounce the final syllable more like *chun* than *chin*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never heard the pronunciation "kweshtin." The "tion" in "question" is said "chin," or at least that's what I've heard. (Californian here, it may be different where you come from.)

Comment: Yeah that's why I mentioned where I grew up in the question. I asked my older sister about it and she said that she pronounces it like me. So that's why I'm kinda torn. Did everyone back home pronounced it as kweshtin or did my sister and I have hearing issues for 10 years?